# Websocket, multipart how to create

Tags: javascript, websocket

I've got a problem, maybe because of my not enough knowledge.

Is there any way to create in javascript an object which contains body(arrayBuffer)which is just raw bytes of file content(let's say PDF document) and add to it content type which is going to be `multipart/form-data`, set its boundaries and somehow file name. Finally convert it back to arrayBuffer and send it via `Websocket` to be readable on the server side(Java) and `MimeMultipart` javaEE object which have methods to `getBodyParts` etc. And to decode this file on server side, these whole raw bytes from websocket to detect what file is it, what is inside the file (pdf content) and other information.

Eventually any other solutions how to co-op in sending large files via websockets?

My idea is to send JSON file first which has META-DATA

```
{ 
    fileName: 'sample'
    filetype: 'pdf'
    size: 200mb
    packets: 10
}
```

and then

```
{
    part: 1, 
    data: [arrayBuffer] 
}
```

etc.
Do you have any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to split your message to parts manually as WebSocket protocol stipulates fragmentation of a message into chunks, you just need to handle a message in the receiver code.https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.4

Comment: Can I open a stream to that file over websocket connection? And handle it from server side for eg. Inputstream(Java)? Lets say stream to movie which weights 5GB?

Comment: I believe that it is possible, but I don't familiar with Java, only on basic level, so unfortunately I can't help you with the issue. I've just mentioned that splitting a message manually could be redundant. Sorry :-)